# Should I be using routing for this? Or just if else?

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am dong some reactjs and wondering if I should be using if/else conditions or if I should be using routing.

I have a standard layout(header,side bar, main content area). When you click on something on the side bar it will load something in main content area. The content is in 2 components and will load depending on which link is clicked.

I am wondering is this a use case for routing or is routing more for if the entire page was changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a use case for routing. In fact, it's the more common usecase for routing. Not to say changing the entire page isn't a good usecase for routing either.

Routing helps navigation in your application no matter what that looks like.